# Spotify SDK loginWithSession causes error Code 6

Tags: ios, swift, spotify

**Edit: Problem solved, the player wasn't initialised with the correct token**

---

I'm trying to play a music from a restored `SPTSession` (from `NSUserDefaults`) with the Spotify's player `SPTAudioStreamingController` from the Spotify's iOS SDK.

When I call the method `loginWithSession` from the `SPTAudioStreamingController`, I've an error in the callback:

```
Error Domain=com.spotify.ios-sdk.playback Code=6 "A playback function was invoked before playback was initalized properly." UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=A playback function was invoked before playback was initalized properly.}
```

Here is my code to login the player with session:

```
self.player.loginWithSession(mySession, callback: { [unowned self] error in
  print("SPOTIFY DEBUG: \(__FUNCTION__) - SESSION => isValid: \(mySession.isValid()) - accessToken: \(mySession.accessToken) - PLAYER: => loggedIn \(self.player.loggedIn)")
})
```

The output:

```
SPOTIFY DEBUG: play - SESSION => isValid: true - accessToken: myValidToken - PLAYER: => loggedIn false
```

I guess the error is due to an invalid `SPTSession` passed as parameter but the debug log show me that the session is valid.

I don't have any idea about how to track this bug. Any suggestion is very welcomed.